# Does accepting a heavily downvoted answer make closing a question more likely?

Tags: discussion, voting, closed-questions, down-votes

I was wondering, if an answer gets a lot of downvotes but the OP is accepting that answer, will a moderator be likely to close the question?

I am talking about a few vote downs around 3. Will the question still remain?

Comment: @shawizdoward It seems you've slightly altered the question asked. I think the OP was referring to accepting a heavily downvoted answer. If this is not the case, please clarify Shaik.

Comment: @shawizdoward i am sorry if my english is bad but i was refering to accepting a heavily downvoted answer.

Comment: Cheers, glad @Bart understood correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That entirely depends on the question. There is no guarantee it will stay around though. Accepting an answer does not prevent deletion. Nor does accepting a heavily downvoted answer make deletion any more likely.

Comment: so moderators will only close a question if they see its really unstructured and improper?

Comment: @shaikibrahim Yes. Questions get closed because the question is somehow problematic. If this is not the case, there is no reason to close/delete it. Do you perhaps have a practical example you're thinking of?

Comment: i got one example but its not so bad [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210615/php-echo-to-html-page/17210728#17210728)

Comment: @shaikibrahim Yeah, that question is not all that great. That's what caused it to be closed. Your answer will not have influenced that one bit. That also means you might want to consider the quality of a question before answering it. You might be wasting your time if you start answering questions which are likely to be deleted.

Comment: But at the end of the day if the user gets what he or she wants i don't see a point of closing it. Isn't that why Stack Overflow was made? to find your desired answer or something similar to it?

Comment: @shaikibrahim No, not really. Stack Overflow was created to end up with a quality repository of questions and answers for the wider community to use. The OPs getting the answers to their immediate questions is a part of that, but not the most important. Quality is strictly controlled on these sites to be as good a repository as it is. And that means some questions get closed, whether they are useful to the OP or not.

Comment: I see!!! Well thanks bard i will try to make my new questions more structured But my english is still not good thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, and good luck! Practice makes perfect. ;)